# Is showing a matrix A is injective the same as showing that $A^3$=e?

Tags: representation-theory

Is showing a matrix A is injective the same as showing that $A^3$=e?

Let G=$C_6$={1,$g$,$g^2$,$g^3$,$g^4$,$g^5$}. 
Is the representation determined by

$$p(g)=\begin{matrix}0 & 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0\end{matrix}$$

faithful?

The definition I have of faithful representation is that a representation is faithful if kernel($p$)=e or if $p$ is injective.

I was trying to show that p(g) is injective to show that it is therefore faithful.
So, does $AAA$=$A^3$=e mean that A is injective, hence a faithful representation?

I don't know how I would show that kernel($p$)=e which is why I was trying to show that p(g) is injective.

Thanks

Comment: $A^3$ sorry typo

Comment: By e, do you mean the identity matrix?

Comment: yeah, the identity matrix

Comment: You're using $e$ with two different meanings.

Comment: how so? that is how it is written in my notes

Comment: $A^3=I$ tells us that $A$ is injective, but the converse is not true.

Comment: @user150068 "I.e. $\text{ker}(p)=e$" and $A^3=e$. In the first one $e$ is the null matrix. In the second it is the identity matrix.

Comment: What drhab said. In your question you said "is the same as showing". This means that the assertions are equivalent. This isn't so. But one implication does hold.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confusing representations of groups being injective (faithful)
$$
\rho: G \to GL_3(\mathbb{C})
$$
with matrices being injective. These are different. Any matrix in the image of a representation is injective, in fact bijective, just because $g\in G$ is invertible. If you say what $G$ is (I suspect $\mathbb{Z}/3$) then we can say whether this representation is faithful.

EDIT: in response to your edited question. You know that $A^3$ is the identity matrix. So what is $\rho(g^3)$? What is $\rho(e)$? Can the representation be faithful?

Comment: In other words: any $n$ by $n$ matrix gives a map $\mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{C}^n$ and it is a meaningful question whether that map is injective. A group representation is a map of groups $G \to GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ (say) and it is a meaningful question whether that is injective too, but a different question about a different object.

Comment: Finally, if $M$ is a matrix in the image of a group representation, it is automatically bijective as a map $\mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{C}^n$, becuase $gg^{-1} = 1$ in $G$ so that $M$ is invertible, so knowing this tells you nothing about whether the representation itself is faithful or not. Hope this helps.

Comment: I have added extra detail to the question now.

Comment: $p(e)$ is the identity matrix?
how would i find $p(g^3)$?

Comment: Well, $\rho$ is a homomorphism. You know $\rho(g)$. You know $(\rho(g))^3$.

Comment: is it the same as $(p(g))^3$?

Comment: Is the kernel is the set of representations that sends g to the identity matrix?

Comment: The kernel of a group map $G \to H$ is the pre-image of the identity. I think you will understand what is going on here better if you re-read the definitions a bit, then come back to this specific problem.

Comment: I can't get my head round it. the kernel of p(g) is the set of elements of G which p($g_i$)=e, so if a representation is faithful only when the kernel=e doesn't that mean that the only element in G which p sends to e is e? i am so confused

Comment: The only definitions I have relating to this question are
kernel($p$)={x in G : p(x)=$1_G$} and 
A representation is faithful if kernel($p$)=e or equivalently if p is injective.

Comment: yes. your representation is not faithful because it has a kernel with more than one element; namely, the kernel is $\{1, g^3 \}$. I think if you start from the beginning you will feel less confused.

Comment: but the identity matrix wouldn't map p(g) to e it would map p(g) to itself?

Comment: so how can the kernel contain 1?

Answer (score 0):

If by $e$, you mean the identity matrix (usually denoted by $I$), then the answer is a resounding no. Take, for example, the matrix $A=2\cdot I$ which has a third power of $8\cdot I\neq I$.

Comment: I do not understand the question and now i do not understand this answer too.... :O